# refresh a part of a page using struts without using ajax 

Tags: java, struts

Guys, is it possible to refresh a part of a page in struts without using ajax. kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a JavaScript function to the page which loads a string from somewhere and assigns it to `innerHtml` of some element.

To invoke the function, either use a timer or call it when the user clicks on a button or a link.

If you need a more specific answer, ask a more specific question, please.

Comment: @Aaron you soultion is without ajax , i.e. using iframe

Comment: No iframe, just use a `DIV` or any other basic HTML element. Note that the web browser will "hang" while your code is executed (which is the main reason for AJAX).

Comment: @Aaron can we refresh a div element from server without refreshing whole page.

Comment: Using AJAX, it's possible to change anything inside the <DIV> tag. Without refresh the whole page.

Comment: But the OP asked **"without using ajax"**